# Get email size using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, gmail-api, google-apps

I have written this to extract last 500+ message from gmail into spreadsheets.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var frm = messages[j].getFrom();
      var to = messages[j].getTo();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();

      ss.appendRow([frm, to, dat])
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the size of each email (with attachment and without attachment)? When I look into documentation of [Gmail message method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/#gmailmessage), there is no any function I could use.

Comment: You can [get the size of attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#getSize()). And you can [get the raw content as a string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getRawContent()) then get the length of the string. Not sure that would be much good to you, though.

Comment: In addition to the above,  For plain messages, You can use `Utilities.newBlob(raw content string).getBytes().length`

Comment: Thank you guys. You rock! (I can not mentions 2 users in this comment)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@s1c0j1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7498443/s1c0j1) and [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster). I could get the size of an email by using this function.

```
var size = Utilities.newBlob(messages[j].getRawContent()).getBytes().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

the user.messages.get returns a [user.messages.response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) which contains a parameter called "sizeEstimate"

> sizeEstimate   integer Estimated size in bytes of the message.

You will need to remember that this is an estimate.